# Implement interface using custom type without importing package

Tags: go, types, interface

Suppose there's a 3rd party package that makes an interface available:

```
package giantpackage

type UselessInfo struct {
    wontUse     string
    alsoWontUse string
}

type CoolInterface interface {
    DoSomethingAwesome(ui UselessInfo) (string, error)
}
```

It seems easy to implement as such:

```
package main

import giantpackage

type Jedi struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func (j Jedi) DoSomethingAwesome(ui giantpackage.UselessInfo) (string, error)
    return "Hello world.", nil
}
```

**Assuming:**
1) I don't actually use the UselessInfo struct in my DoSomethingAwesome function.
2) The package that I have to import is HUGE.
3) The package that I have to import is no longer maintained, and cannot be modified.

**My question:**
Is there any way to implement CoolInterface without importing giantpackage?

Comment: @JimB Except that this method has a parameter with a type defined in that package.

Comment: @icza, Yeah, that wasn't worded well, I meant to highly the _implicitly_ part. It should be obvious you need to import the package to put that package's type in the method.

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem - if you have a need to implement this specific interface, then logically *you must already be importing this package in your application*. It doesn't matter if a particular *file* imports a package, what matters is whether *anywhere in the application* imports a package.

Comment: Then you should segregate any code that references that package into its own package. Then people that need it can import it, and those that don't won't have to take on the transient dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not.

To implement the `giantpackage.CoolInterface`, your type must have a method:

```
DoSomethingAwesome(giantpackage.UselessInfo) (string, error)
```

And to have a method that matches this signature, you have to import `giantpackage`, else using any other type for the parameter, it won't match the required method.

In your comments you indicated you plan to create a library, and providing an implementation of this interface will be a "nice to have" feature to *some* of the users of your library.

Then the recommended way is to create a "core" package of your library which does **not** contain this interface implementation and thus does not depend on `giantpackage`. Users of your library that do not need this will only import your "core" package and so they will also not depend on `giantpackage`.

Create another "extension" package of your library which will contain the implementation of this interface (and which may also use your "core" package if needed). Users that do need this can import this package as well.